# How to update after insert in the same table in an Oracle trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a table with columns X, Y and Z. I want to set Z when I insert or update X and Y, so Z=X*Y, using a trigger.

```
create or replace trigger tr_tab
after insert
on tab
for each row
begin
update tab
set z=x*y;
end;
/
```

But after insert I get an error.

Comment: @newbie - it's helpful to state the error you get - presumably a mutating table error here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't (and can't, generally) update the row you're inserting; you need to change what is being inserted by setting the new Z value for the current row:

```
create or replace trigger tr_tab
before insert or update
on tab
for each row
begin
  :new.z := :new.x * :new.y;
end;
/
```

This refers to the inserted/updated row using [the `:new` pseudorecord syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955).

This needs to be a before-insert trigger to manipulate the `:new` value for a column; an after-insert for-each-row trigger fires to late to make that change.

You could have an after-insert statement level trigger - i.e. what you showed in the question but with the `for each row` line removed - but that would update Z for every row in the table even if nothing had changed, doing much more work and generating unnecessary redo. (Read more about the trigger types [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99888)).

You also have the option of making Z [a virtual column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#BABIJABG) that is generated automatically from the values of other columns, without needing a trigger.

Comment: i get this error.PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
following:
:= . ( @ % ; indicator
The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.

Comment: @newbie - yes, sorry, typo; should be `:=` for PL/SQL assignment. Fixed.

Comment: now. i get this error. cannot change new values for this trigger type

Comment: @newbie - correct; I should be paying more attention. You need a before-insert trigger. (Or your original after-insert but at table level, without `for each row` - but that would recalculate the value for all rows, which isn't necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the new inserted values to do that

```
update tab
set :new.z=:new.x*:new.y;
```

And if you want to difference between insertions and updates you can do it like this:

```
if (inserting or updating) then
        //Do things
end if;
```

All the information you need to create your trigger is in this page:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm

Comment: after insert i get an error " is mutating , trigger/function may not see it"